# Total variation on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, bounded-variation

The total variation of differentiable function $f$ on the closed interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ is [given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189889/proof-v-abf-int-ab-fxdx) by
$$V_a^b(f)=\int_a^b|f'(x)|dx.$$
Does the same formula hold for the total variation of differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., can we say that the total variation of a function on $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\int_\mathbb{R}|f'(x)|dx$ (given that the last integral is finite)?

If the formula indeed holds, is there any book or other reference where it is proved?

Almost all the sources that I have checked deal with the variation on finite intervals paying almost no attention to variations on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Take at look at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269198/bounded-variation-on-the-entire-real-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this clarifies a few things for the OP:

If $f$ is absolutely continuous on every compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$, then  $f$ is of locally finite variation,  $f'$ exits and is locally integrable and
$$\begin{align}
f(b)-f(a)&=\int^b_a f'(t)\,dt\\
V(f;a,b)&=\int_{(a,b]}|f'(t)|\,dt
\end{align}$$

If in addition $f'\in L_1(\mathbb{R}$,  then $f(-\infty):=\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}f(a)$ and $f(\infty)=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}f(b)$ exist, are finite, and
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(-\infty)-\int_{(-\infty,x]}f'(t)\,dt\\
f(x)&=f(\infty)-\int_{(x,\infty)}f'(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$
Furthermore, the measure $\mu_{f'}(A)=\int_Af'(t)\,dt$ is a Radon measure, its variation measure is given by $|\mu_{f'}|(A)=\int_A|f'(t)|\,dt$, and it has total finite variation $\|\mu_{f'}\|_{TV}=\int_\mathbb{R}|f'|$.